# What exactly does pure degree mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently learning about cohomology in algebraic topology. I have already taken abstract algebra, but I've never encountered the notion of an element having "pure degree". So what does it mean?

Explicitely, it is often stated that particular formulas or statements only hold for cycles or cocycles of pure degree. But what does it mean for a cycle $c \in S_p(X)$ or a cocycle $\varphi \in S^p(X;G)$ to have pure degree?

Comment: Context?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An element of a graded ring $R^*$ has pure degree $k$ if it lies in $R^k$. The prototypical example is the polynomial ring $R[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ (with each $\deg X_i = 1$), where a polynomial of degree $k$ is pure of degree $k$ iff it's homogeneous (that is, the sum of monomials that all have total degree $k$). That having been said, "pure degree" is often abbreviated just to "degree" if the context is clear (as it usually is in algebraic topology; differential forms of mixed degree, for example, are generally less interesting than their pure-degree counterparts).

Comment: Thanks, this helped! But then I don't understand why the words "pure degree" are added, if one writes that for example $c \in S_p(X)$ has pure degree. Because if $c \in S_p(X)$ then it is clear that it has pure degree. Might this just be to really point out that the element has pure degree or am I still missing the point?

Comment: Yes, it's just there to emphasize that it's in $S_p(X)$ rather than the larger space $S_0(X) \oplus \cdots \oplus S_p(X)$. It's very common to just say that $c$ has degree $p$.